# VBA Excel paste value confusion

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried to implement similar code from a post that contained this code.
it works great copying from specified cells but I need it to paste the **cell values** from the source not the cell contents(formula etc.) have tried several things but all give errors
TIA

```
Sub AlonsoApprovedList()

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rngDest As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim arrColsToCopy

    arrColsToCopy = Array(1, 3, 4, 5)

    '----For every cell in row G on the ESI Project Data sheet----'
    Set rngDest = Worksheets("Alonso Approved List").Range("A3")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each cell In Worksheets("ESI Project Data").Range("G6:G5000").Cells

        If cell.Value = "Card" Then

            For i = LBound(arrColsToCopy) To UBound(arrColsToCopy)
                With cell.EntireRow
                    .Cells(arrColsToCopy(i)).Copy rngDest.Offset(0, i)
                End With
            Next i

            Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(1, 0) 'next destination row

        End If

    Next cell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rngDest.Offset(0, i).Value = .Cells(arrColsToCopy(i)).Value
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this gives a run-time error"13:Type mismatch

Comment: All I did was flip your working line around and change it to directly assign values: no idea why you're seeing that error.

Comment: My actual code is very similar to the example I can send it if needed this runs fine except it puts the formualas etc.      array32=VALUE(A1)which equates to 0.687 ,array33=VALUE(B1)which equates to 0.687,array36=VALUE(B1)which equates to T365

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize you flipped the code I just replaced the rngDest.Offset(0, i) with rngDest.Offset(0, i).Value works great thanks for the help